# Filtering GORM objects based on attribute grails

Tags: grails, hql, grails-orm

I have a filter, for example lets assume the name `John Doe` is who a user is searching for.

I have the following domain object structure: `Company--->Employee--->Name`. Where employee is an attribute of company, and name is an attribute of employee. Now, the filter is for the name attribute, but I need to keep a reference to the Company. So for example I did:

```
companyList.events.each {
if(it.employee!=null){
      if(it.employee.name.toString().toLowerCase().contains(filter)){  
         filterSet.add(it)
      }
}
```

Unfortunately, this operation is very slow for 1500 entries. However if I do something like,

```
def searchResults = Company.findAll{
    employee.name == filter
}
```

It is very fast, but I need the filter to get matched with partial names (i.e. saying `Joh` would still match `John Doe`. I know there is an operation called `like` but I have been unsuccessful using it.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you look at using [criteria](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html). So in this case you could do this:

```
def filter = 'joh'
def searchResults = Company.createCriteria().list() {
  employee {
    ilike('name', "%${filter}%")
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Perfect, just what I needed. I'll accept as soon as I can

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Company.findAll ("from Company c where c.employee.name like '%'| |:filterName| |'%'", [filterName: yourFilterName])

This query has to be fast.